# Pausing Java Code (Netbeans), then Resuming Execution

Tags: java, netbeans

So I'm looking for a similar statement to C++:    System("pause");

That runs the code up until a certain point, await's user/keyboard input to continue [Enter], then proceeds.

Everything I can find talks about kill commands, exit systems, threads, etc that basically just close the program down (useful if it's stuck but not for my purposes).  The only other references I could find here were to literally pause the program for a set amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Scanner class. You can do it like this:

```
      System.out.println("Press enter to continue");
      new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```